# How parse all requests in Charles except one

Tags: iphone, proxy, app-store, charles-proxy

I want to parse all requests from iPhone but when I use "*" in SSL Settings Appstore application does not work.

[image]

So, I want to exclude requests to Appstore/Apple from parsing.

I tried exclude them in recording settings, but it does not work.

Is it possible exclude some requests from parsing and still parse all other?

Comment: have somebody  any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

Open the **Proxy > Proxy Settings > Options** tab and add domains to the bypass textarea according to this information:

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/proxy-settings/

Or there is another way:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25424